# ViewPager swipe not working properly over scroll recylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, swipe

I am using a `viewPager` for switching between 2 `Fragments`. i can easily swipe from **FragmentTwo** to **FragmentOne** and when i try swipe from **FragmentOne** to **FragmentTwo**, it don't swipe but it swipe only when i touch at the most right corner on the FirstFragment. I think the problem is in my adapter of the recyclerView.

#### A [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG3pS.jpg) on it.

[image]

Code for *recyclerView* in **FirstFragment**

```
recyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_home)
            val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerView?.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager


            postList = ArrayList()
            postAdapter = context?.let { PostAdapter(it, postList as ArrayList<Post>) }
            recyclerView?.adapter = postAdapter
```

And the XML code of ViewPager in **MainActivity**

```
  <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

code for viewPager in **MainActivity**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mViewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager_main_activity)
        mViewPager?.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, 2)
        mViewPager?.offscreenPageLimit = 2
    
        setupViewPager(mViewPager) }

internal class MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, two: Int):FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    private val fragments: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getItem(position:Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                return MainFragment()
            }
            1 ->{
                return MessengerFragment()
            }
        }
        return fragments[position]
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your fragments layout code too

Comment: hay @AminMousavi i edited my question please check it.

Comment: hmmm. I can't see any problem in your code. But it seems you are using the old `ViewPager`. I would suggest to refactor your code to use `ViewPager2` and see if the problem still exists or not.

Comment: @AminMousavi Thank you, you were right about viewpager2. It solved my problem. i was using custom viewPager where it disabled any type of TouchListener.